# HTML form with submit to php. Displaying php response

Tags: php, html

I am trying to implement a 'reset password' page for my website. So far I have a simple page with a form for the user to enter their email address. Submitting the form calls 'requestpasswordreset.php' which does things such as checking if there exists a user with that email, sending the password reset email out etc.

```
<body>
<form name="input" action="requestpasswordreset.php" method="post">
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"> </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
</body>
```

requestpasswordreset.php pseudocode

```
if no user with email = $_POST['email']
    echo 'No user exists with this email';
else
   ...
   doStuff();
   echo 'Password reset email sent';
```

I would like to know how I could do the following:

If the user entered an invalid email address, the form would remain visible and an error message would be displayed.

If the request was successfull the form would be hidden, and a message saying something like 'success' would be displayed.

It seems like it would be unnecessary/bad practice to redirect to a new page in either case? rather than just updating the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not bad practise to redirect, or in other way make a [postback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback), at all. The solution you are looking for is called AJAX, and both solutions are equally viable. You could use javascript (and maybe [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) to query the server, and then hiding the form/give an error message depending on the servers response.

You cannot validate or send emails without a postback in html and php only, if that is your question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an error you would just output the same HTML with an added error message from your PHP script. If it is successful, you could redirect them elsewhere, or keep them on the same page as you see fit. I would probably bring them back to the log in form, with a success message added personally for easy access to log in once they get that email from you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try submitting form to the same page? Then

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) /** and user exists **/) {
  /** do whatever you need to do **/
} else {
  /** display the form **/
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do somthing like that :

on your php code :

> if( email is wrong )
>   echo"window.location.href='yourformpage.php?email=wrong'";
>   else
>   doStuff();

and in your form page :

> if(isset($_GET['email']) AND $_GET['email'] == 'wrong')
>
> echo "display error message";

Comment: window.location.href is not php.